# Is there a shorthand for using functions on a variable?

Tags: php

Example:

```
$json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'] = utf8_encode($json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name']);
```

With enough nesting, this can become very long and unreadable.
Is there a way to avoid having to type the same variable twice?

Something like

```
$json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'] = utf8_encode($this);
```

I know you could do

```
$a = $json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'];
$a = utf8_encode($a);
```

but that's also relatively inconvenient.

Comment: Ask for *one* language at a time. With multiple languages, this is (at least) two different questions whereas you should be asking one question at a time.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not aware of any syntax or language feature in JS and PHP that works this way. Either make a variable or restructure your code.

Comment: You could write a function to handle this if it's something you will be repeating and want some sort of shorthand way to handle it

Comment: `$a = $json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name']; $a = utf8_encode($a);` looks fine to me. As @tshimkus suggests, you could put this into a function if you don't want to repeat yourself.

Comment: Am I missing something or couldn't you just do, `$a = utf8_encode($json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try pass by reference (using the `&` sign), like:

```php
$ref = & $json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'];
$ref = utf8_encode($ref);
```

The `&` (ampersand sign) ensures to update the `$json` array automatically, without that it could look like below:

```php
$x = $json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'];
$x = utf8_encode($x);
$json['errorinfo']['customers']['some_swedish_name'] = $x;
```